# ubuntu touch on galaxy tab 3 p5210

Tags: ubuntu-touch, samsung

sorry for my english

i was thinking in buy a samsung galaxy tab 3 p5210 in christmast but before i want to know if i could install ubuntu touch

i wathed that is available for galaxy tab 2 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQH2rlEgnJE  and http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=40846174Please
but i dont found noting about samsung galaxy tab 3

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like there is much information online for that particular device. I would assume that it isn't yet possible to install Ubuntu Touch on it yet.

If you are looking for a device to buy, you would probably be much better off looking [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices) at the supported devices.

Comment: And the Galaxy Tab 3 10.1" is unusual in that is has an **Intel Atom Z2560** (and not an ARM) processor. *You would do best to first try out Ubuntu Touch on a **Nexus 7** (1st Gen).*